# Eleição Para Moderadores da Comunidade 2020

Tags: debate, eleição, moderadores

Começaram as Eleições para Moderadores 2020!

Teremos 3 períodos diferentes durante as eleições:

1. Candidatura
2. Primárias
3. Eleições

Eleições costumam durar entre duas e três semanas, mas isso varia de acordo com o número de candidatos.  Para mais detalhes, e saber como participar, visite  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/election

Caso você tenha mais perguntas sobre o processo de eleição, ou para os candidatos, pergunte no meta!   Basta usar a tag [eleição](/questions/tagged/elei%c3%a7%c3%a3o).